# Drupal 8 Installation Is Just Plain HTML

Tags: 8, installation

I just installed Drupal 8 in a subdirectory. I pushed all of the files to the directory, I installed Drupal with a minimal setup and and edited my .htaccess file to make Drupal work with my subdirectory. Now, it displays my website, but without any CSS or Javascript. It's just plain HTML text. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: That depends what is broken. From what you wrote, we can't even know if JS and CSS files are even there. And if they are, we don't know if Drupal generated entries for them. If it did, what HTTP status codes you got? What's in your logs? and so on, and so on.

Comment: @Molot I'm not entirely sure how to find HTTP status codes. However, I have one warning in my logs. It says, `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/8/d197535321/htdocs/KrisKendallSites/MatchFont/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:361) in Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->destroy() (line 267 of /homepages/8/d197535321/htdocs/KrisKendallSites/MatchFont/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionManager.php).` Also, I think it might be worth mentioning that "index.php" keeps showing up in my addresses.

Comment: In Chrome, for example, hit F12, go to Network and reload page.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I just solved the problem. I didn't realize that by default on a Minimal installation that the Stark theme, which is simply a plain HTML theme, was enabled by default. I switched the theme and now it works fine.